# Access this.$fireStore in vuex action (Nuxt.js)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, vuefire

[Here](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/guide/usage/#examples) it is stated that *$fireStore* could be accessed inside *vuex action*:

```
async randomVuexAction({ commit, state, rootState }, userId) {
  const ref = this.$fireStore.collection('users').doc(userId)
  ...
}
```

**Problem:** After triggering action in `store/index.js`:

```
addItem: ({ commit, getters }, itemName) => {
  const item = { name: itemName }
  this.$fireStore.collection('items').add(item).then((res) => {})
}
```

I'm getting error: `Cannot read property '$fireStore' of undefined`. Generally speaking, `console.log(this)` inside all actions except `nuxtServerInit()` - gives `undefined`. So is it even possible to utilize `$fireStore` in `vuex` or documentation is misleading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the arrow notation for your action (because 'this' does not refer to the same thing with arrow notation) i.e.

```
addItem ({ commit, getters }, itemName) {
  const item = { name: itemName }
  this.$fireStore.collection('items').add(item).then((res) => {})
}
```

Note: the same applies to computed properties and methods in Vue components. Follow the docs, don't change things for the sake of it.